# Is it possible to crawl by <body> tag in stormcrawler?

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

Now I am using stormcrawler for crawling website.
I want to know it is possible to crawl by `<body>` tag or  something  others like `<article>` in storm crawler.
I modified the parsefilters.json file like below but it didn't work

```
{
  "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.filter.ContentFilter",
  "name": "ContentFilter",
  "params": {
    "pattern": "//ARTICLE",
    "pattern": "//BODY"
   }
}
```

Please advise me how to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What the ContentFilter does is to restrict the text extracted from the HTML to the span covered by the XPath expressions if they match. Is that what you are trying to achieve? Could it be that the crawler is getting a different content from what you are seeing e.g. it is dynamically generated? If you can see the tag when using curl on that URL, so should StormCrawler.

Comment: How can I  crawl by <article> tag and index into the another field named "article"? Can it be implemented by configuration?

Comment: Crawl is not the right term. If you mean extract the content of the field the way to do it depends on whether you want this to be the main field of the document or not. If yes, then use the ContentFilter as you did above then set indexer.text.fieldname in the config to 'article'. If you want to preserve the content of the whole document in  a separate field but have article as well then use the XPathFilter instead and configure it with "article": "//ARTICLE"
Remember to set article in indexer.md.mapping so that the metadata gets indexed.